# SQL Server: pivoting without aggregation on a table with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is a question on a test. I have a table with two columns. I want to pivot on one of them and output the other.

Table structure:

```
(Name varchar(10), Age int)
```

I need output with age values as columns and Names listed below each age value.

From searching, I only see examples where there is at least one other column that is used to "group by" for want of a better term. In other words, there is a common factor in each row of the output. My problem does not have this property.

I tried:

```
SELECT  
    [agevalue1], [agevalue2], [agevalue3], [agevalue4]
FROM
    (SELECT Name, Age FROM MyClass) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (MAX(Name)
       FOR Age IN ([agevalue1], [agevalue2], [agevalue3], [agevalue4])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

I specified agevalue* as a string, i.e. in quotes. I got the column headings alright but a row of NULLS below them.

P.S.: The solution does not need to use pivot but I couldn't think of an alternative approach.

Sample Data:

```
  Name  Age

  Bob   11
  Rick  25
  Nina  30
  Sam   11
  Cora  16
  Rachel 25
```

Desired output:

```
    11    16    25    30
  Bob  Cora  Rick    Nina
  Sam  NULL  Rachel  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
with tab as
(
Select 'A' Name, 10 Age union all
Select 'B',11 union all
Select 'c',10 union all
Select 'D',11 union all
Select 'E',11 union all
Select 'F',11 
)
select distinct
Age
, stuff((
    select ',' + g.Name 
    from tab g        
    where g.age = g1.age        
    order by g.age
    for xml path('')
        ),1,1,'') as Names_With_Same_Age
from tab g1
group by g1.age,Name
```

Comment: This resulted in output getting printed horizontally as in:  10 A,c </n> 11 B,D,E,F

Answer (score 0):

To group these together in one row:

```
11    16    25    30
 Bob  Cora  Rick    Nina
```

and separate them from another set, like:

```
11    16    25    30
Sam  NULL  Rachel  NULL
```

they must have something different between each row, since doing a `MAX(Name)` would get you only one Name for each Age.

This query creates a number that links a particular `Age` to a row number and then pivots the result. As you said, the `PIVOT` will group by all columns not referenced in the `PIVOT` function, so it will group by this row indexer, separating the values like you wanted.

```
;WITH IndexedClass AS
(
    SELECT
        M.Name,
        M.Age,
        -- The ordering will determine which person goes first for each Age
        RowIndexer = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.Age ORDER BY M.Name) 
    FROM
        MyClass AS M
)
SELECT
    P.[11],
    P.[16],
    P.[25],
    P.[30]
FROM
    IndexedClass AS I
    PIVOT (
        MAX(I.Name) FOR I.Age IN ([11], [16], [25], [30])
    ) AS P
```